# Can I have a "semi-private" google action?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, home-automation

I'm attempting to write a google action that is only intended for use by me and my immediate family. I have it working currently in the simulator, and on my device, but I haven't "released" it yet.

This may be a result of it being still in the testing phase, but it seems to be able to be invoked only by my google account. Everything I do with the action works, but neither my wife nor kids can use it; they just get "I don't understand".

What do I have to do to allow other voice-recognized google accounts to be able to use my action?

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional - your Action is currently in a "development" state. While you can permit it to other developers, this isn't a great approach.

You can "release" it into an [Alpha channel](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments) and let a limited number of accounts have access to the Alpha channel version. This isn't quite a "private" action, but it doesn't require review from Google, and it does let you limit which accounts have access to it. Once they're in the Alpha channel, they can activate the Action just like public Actions.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that sound exactly like what I should be doing. On my "Manage Releases" page however, the only option I have is "Submit for Production". Is there some option I missed to allow the Alpha and Beta channels?

Comment: That seems odd. I've added a picture. If you don't see that - send a message to tech support.

Comment: Emailed tech support. They said that alpha and beta channels are not supported for Smart Home actions. That seems like a super bummer. The only option I believe I have is to "release" my app for public consumption despite it being only intended for my family.

Comment: Smart Home actions go through additional review and testing process as well. Your alternative is to turn it into a conversational action.